# moderncv adding title to letter?

Tags: moderncv, letters, cv

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             
\moderncvcolor{green}                            
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{\raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}}{\raggedright\hintstyle{#2}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}
                              {\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=1cm]{unterschrift.jpg}
                              \vspace{-10pt}\par
                               \bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}
                              {}{}
\makeatother
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Lebenslauf}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{asdfdsf 12}{77777 scity}{Germany}
\phone[mobile]{+49~(xxx)~xxx~xxx}                   %
\phone[fixed]{+49~(xxx)~xxx~xxx}
\email{XXXXX}                               
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
\usepackage{ifthen}       % <===========================================
\newboolean{CV}
\setboolean{CV}{false}    % <===========================================
\newboolean{Letter}
\setboolean{Letter}{true} % <===========================================
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{CV}}{% print CV
\makecvtitle
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.195\textwidth}
\section{Hobbys}
\cvlistitem{dance}
\cvlistitem{chess}
\cvlistitem{cook}
\cvlistitem{swim}
\ \\
\ \\
\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=1cm]{unterschrift.jpg} \\
ccity, 10. Oktober 2017
\clearpage
}{% print no CV
}
\title{Bewerbung um XXX}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{Letter}}{% print Cover Letter
\recipient{Xxxy}{Xxxxx\\XXXXX\\XXXXXXXX}
\date{ccity, 10.10.2017}
\opening{\textbf{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren},}
\closing{Mit freundlichen Gr"u"sen,}
\enclosure[Im Anhang]{Lebenslauf}          
\makelettertitle

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue.
\makeletterclosing

}{% print no Cover Letter
}

\end{document}
```

I want to add a title to my letter. The \title{} doesn't print any title. Can someone please help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. a file starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want to add a title  to the cover letter ? or Do you want to customize the cover letter to include more information ? -- which version of moderncv are you using ? v0.6, v1.2 or v.2.0 ?

Comment: I added full working sample, I think I have the version 1.3c

Comment: I want customize the cover letter to include more information not add a huge title on the top.

Answer (score 7):

In [moderncv](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), the classic cover letter  does not use the information you provide in the `\title`. Basically, it was written to create that page without providing any title.

**How the cover letter is created**

A cover letter is created using some macros to provide information, a macro to create a header and other to create the signature and footer:

```
\clearpage                             % start a new page

\recipient{ ... }                      % provide information
\opening{ ... }
\closing{ ... }
\enclosure[ ... ]{ ... }
\makelettertitle                       % print title / header

...                                    % print content
\makeletterclosing                     % print letter footer / signature
```

The `\makelettertitle` and `\makeletterclosing` do not use the information of the title (`@title`) to create the content.

**How to add a title**

At the end, A moderncv document is a LaTeX document. You can add content before or after the header provided by the template. For instance, you can add a title before the header or after the salutation.

```
\clearpage                             % start a new page
\recipient{ ... }                      % provide information
...

{\centering \Huge Add a title \par}    % add a text before header
\makelettertitle                       % print title / header
{\Huge Add another title \par}         % add a text after header
```

**Modifying moderncv**

You may be interested on modifying the moderncv template. You can [get the source code from Github](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv).

If you want to change the code, note that `moderncv` has many "styles". The `\makelettertitle` is defined empty in the `moderncv.cls` file.

```
% makes the letter title
% usage: \makelettertitle
\newcommand*{\makelettertitle}{}    % for the version v1.2.0
```

The macro is redefined in each style. For instance, if you use the *classic* style, that style is defined in `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` file. You must look for the `\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}` in the file for the style you are using and change the code.

```
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
   \recomputeletterlengths%
   :
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `banking` moderncvstyle prints a title in the letter head. If you want to use a moderncvstyle of your choice, you will have to redefine the `makeletterhead` command.